# Два процесса приложения

Tags: c#, процесс

Такое дело: ищу процесс своего приложения по имени процесса(имени exe, без расширения)

```
Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
```

Мне его надо потом развернуть, но это не работает так, как надо, т.к. находит два процесса. Сначала думал, что это ещё vshost мешает, но после закрытия VS, оказалось, что это не так. В диспечере показан только один процесс.

Почему так? И как найти именно мой процесс? По имени окна не предлогать.

Comment: То есть вы запустили два экземпляра приложения из app.exe и удивляетесь почему находится два процесса по имени?

Comment: Я запускаю одно приложение, а при втором запуске у меня разворачивается уже запущенное окно. Второго процесса быть никак не может.

Comment: Одно приложение, не вопрос. А сколько раз запускаете-то?

Comment: Сколько захочу, щёлкаю по exe и всё. Не понимаю при чём здесь это. Если я щёлкну больше двух раз, процессов всё-равно будет 2.

Comment: И в чем вопрос? Почему при запуске двух экземпляров у вас два процесса?

Comment: @Сергей на момент поиска приложения у Вас запущено два приложения - собственно Ваше приложение, которое нужно развернуть и приложение, которое Вы запустили. В списке приложений Вы его не видите, потому что оно отрабатывает очень быстро. Посылайте запрос каждому с найденных приложений. Приложение, которое уже давно запущено, развернется, а приложение, которое посылало запрос на разворачивание, знает об этом и не будет разворачиваться.

Comment: Получается, MessageBox будет виден не зависимо от того, закрыто приложение или нет? Просто у меня в методе, который вызывается при запуске дубликата, выводится сообщение о количестве процессов. Если их не закрывать, то они просто копятся, но получается они уже работают не зависимо от своих процессов, раз вы говорите, что процесс быстро отрабатывает?

Comment: @Сергей это было предположение. Если там долго висит MessageBox - значит, процесс отрабатывает долго.

Comment: Вопроса не понял, но прошу обратить внимание, что в выборку процессов могут попасть принадлежащие другому сеансу Windows на этом же ПК. Я бы не рекомендовал их трогать вообще, но смотрите по логике приложения.

Answer (score 2):

Сергей, судя по выражениям

> Мне его надо потом развернуть...
>
> при втором запуске у меня разворачивается уже запущенное окно...
>
> Сколько захочу, щёлкаю по exe и всё...

сложилось впечатление, что Вам нужна одна копия приложения.
Если я правильно понял, почему бы не воспользоваться готовым решением?
Типа [этого](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/maxim/2010/02/13/single-instance-application-manager/), или поискать "Single Instance Application". На одном "stackoverflow.com" найдется с десяток достойных решений.

Если же у Вас другая задача, внесите в свой вопрос больше подробностей. Поскольку, с ходу не понятно что именно Вы пытаетесь решить.

P.S. К сожалению недостаточно баллов чтобы комментировать, вынужден писать комментарий в качестве ответа.